# Mismatch Sender ID

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications to my phone using the following code:

```
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="xxx")
registration_id = "xxx"
message_title = "New apartment available"
message_body = address + " . Rent: " + str(price) + " €."
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
print(result)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
{'multicast_ids': [8100868610517432850], 
'success': 0, 
'failure': 1, 
'canonical_ids': 0, 
'results': [{'error': 'MismatchSenderId'}], 
'topic_message_id': None}
```

Is there any way to manually set the Server ID? The api_key and the registration_id should be correct.

Comment: Are you positive that you're using the correct server key/API key? Where are you getting it?

Comment: I have tried both the "Web API Key" at Firebase Console > Project Settings > General, and the "Server Key" at Firebase Console > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging